# Custom single-post pulling from wrong custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

So I am setting up a custom WordPress theme using two custom post types Articles and News. Each one is also using a custom `single-post.php` page `single-articles.php` and `single-news.php`. But after pulling the article posts on the main page and inserting their permalink into a 'Read more' link when I click on one of the article's links it takes me to their permalink URL but instead of displaying the article post it displays the News post content. Both `single-articles.php` and `single-news.php` are in the themes folder, not in a subfolder.

Here is an example of how I'm setting up the custom posts...

```
add_action( 'init', 'articles_custom_postypes' );
function articles_custom_postypes() {
$args = array (
'label' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'menu_position' => 100,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-aside',
'label' => 'Articles',
'has_archive' => false,
'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'thumbnail'),

);

register_post_type( 'articles', $args);

}
```

On the custom single post pages I am just calling `the_title()`, `the_content`, etc. Should I be using a while loop or something? Any advice would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to have two files in your theme folder. One is `single-articles.php` and other is `content-articles.php`. If the files are created add the following code to `single-articles.php`.

```
<?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content-articles', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
?>
```

Also add the following to `content-articles.php`.

```
<?php
    the_title();
    the_content();
?>
```

Comment: This is what I have for the front page, to display the first three article posts. But if someone clicks on the link for that article and goes to the single-articles.php page thats where it's showing the news posts instead of the article posts. Wouldn't the code above just pull and list the last ten articles I posted instead of actually querying the article who's link I just clicked and displaying it on my custom single-articles template page?

Comment: Hi Jacob,
I edited my answer. Please look through it. It will solve your problem.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Any clue why this worked? I get pulling part of a template into the page if there's a post, but how is that any different then calling the the_autor, the_content etc into the single-article page directly? Does it have to do with the while have_posts loop? Why wouldn't I just include that at the top of both the single-articles.php and single-news.php instead of putting it in a separate template file and including it in each page? Sorry, I learn best asking questions. Thanks again!

Comment: single-{post type}.php is the page for a post type and content-{post type}.php is the page for displaying corresponding content.